# Spaces in java command line argument

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

I've searched but still don't know how to resolve this. I am trying to setup a batch script to run this Java command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\"java -cp "AddDocument.jar;Jace.jar;p8cel10n.jar;stax-api.jar;xlxpScanner.jar;xlxpScannerUtils.jar;log4j-1.2.15.jar" java -cp "AddDocument.jar;Jace.jar;p8cel10n.jar;stax-api.jar;xlxpScanner.jar;xlxpScannerUtils.jar;log4j-1.2.15.jar" com.ibm.labservices.AddDocument btd047e p8forHJ!Pecm FileNetP8WSI http://hjipuat/wsi/FNCEWS40MTOM HJIP Sample.iso image/jpeg.AddDocument userid password FileNetP8WSI http://hjipuat/wsi/FNCEWS40MTOM HJIP Sample.iso image/jpeg
```

Instead of the command running, I get the java help index.

Answer (score 0):

Your second `"` is in the wrong place.  The first part of the command should be:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\java"
```

with the `"` after `java` not before it.  The complete, correct command is then:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\java" -cp "AddDocument.jar;Jace.jar;p8cel10n.jar;stax-api.jar;xlxpScanner.jar;xlxpScannerUtils.jar;log4j-1.2.15.jar" java -cp "AddDocument.jar;Jace.jar;p8cel10n.jar;stax-api.jar;xlxpScanner.jar;xlxpScannerUtils.jar;log4j-1.2.15.jar" com.ibm.labservices.AddDocument btd047e p8forHJ!Pecm FileNetP8WSI http://hjipuat/wsi/FNCEWS40MTOM HJIP Sample.iso image/jpeg.AddDocument userid password FileNetP8WSI http://hjipuat/wsi/FNCEWS40MTOM HJIP Sample.iso image/jpeg
```

If the command *still* misbehaves after the correction to the pathname, the problem lies with the syntax required by java.exe, not Command Prompt.

Comment: I get the " part - thanks but...

When I run the script command line it works fine but fails in the batch script with error "Could not find or load main class java"

In Task scheduler
-Actions tab
**Program script -** T:\Development\INF-P8\Projects\HealthCheck-2016\testjar\hjip-run-script-load-testfile.bat
**Add argument -** >> c:\temp\testfile.log

My bat file is as follows:

Comment: *echo %DATE%_%TIME% Processing Test File
t:
cd T:\Development\INF-P8\Projects\HealthCheck-2016\testjar
java -cp "AddDocument.jar;Jace.jar;p8cel10n.jar;stax-api.jar;xlxpScanner.jar;xlxpScannerUtils.jar;log4j-1.2.15.jar" java -cp "AddDocument.jar;Jace.jar;p8cel10n.jar;stax-api.jar;xlxpScanner.jar;xlxpScannerUtils.jar;log4j-1.2.15.jar" com.ibm.labservices.AddDocument btd047e p8forHJ!Pecm FileNetP8WSI http://hjipuat/wsi/FNCEWS40MTOM HJIP Sample.iso image/jpeg.AddDocument userid password FileNetP8WSI http://hjipuat/wsi/FNCEWS40MTOM HJIP Sample.iso image/jpeg*

Comment: Please update your question with these details.  Be sure to include the fact you're ultimately trying to run this via Task Scheduler.

Comment: Why do you have the `-cp` argument twice? And is `java` a valid class?

Comment: I am trying to run this via Task Scheduler so I can have it run multiple times throughout the day.

Comment: The actual command I am running I got from our IBM vendor.

Comment: @user757842 In other words you're not sure it's a valid command?

Comment: @user757842 and `-cp` belongs twice? Looking at the syntax help for java it doesn't seem right.

Comment: you are correct, just heard back from IBM, it was a typo...

Comment: the odd part for me was that ran ok from command line so I never even thought....

Comment: @user757842 you mean it ran correctly after fixing the pathname... :-)

Comment: @user757842 Good. Please consider marking the answer accepted and up voting it.